# Unacceptable type of value for attribute - Desired type NSstring

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, nsarray

The tite explains the error :

```
Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "routinename"; desired type = NSString; given type = _NSArrayM;
```

I am adding an array from which the user generates and importing it into a core data entity.

This is done by :

**viewDidLoad**

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.exTitle = array;
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
[self.exTitle addObject: info.name];
```

Which all works fine and adds the value into the array.

To add it to the core data entity I tried:

```
-(IBAction) Done: (id)sender {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines" inManagedObjectContext: context];
[newDevice setValue:exTitle forKey: @"routinename"];
```

I am probably missing something really simple but how do I correct this so I can add the array into the NSString formatted value in the entity.

Comment: How (and why) do you want to convert the array to a string?

Comment: Side note: Is the property called `exTite`, `exTitle` or `extTitle`?? Somehow that makes me doubt that you pasted your real code ...

Comment: @ Martin R ....i had to type the code in from my other computer cause i have no internet access at the moment and my dongle does not work on my mac so i need to use my pc...

Comment: @Wain...I would just like to know if its possible to rectify this problem and how? I just want to add the array values to my core data entity

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly the problem.  The type of object that your Core Data model is expecting for the key "routinename" is a string.  Based on the code you have posted, `extTitle` is an array.

Either fix the data model or, if you need to, you could write a method to convert the array into a string (although you probably should convert to/from an `NSData` object)

Comment: thanks simon. Whats the easiest way to convert to/from an NSData object?

Comment: I tried using `NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:exTitle];` but got the given type as NSConcreteMutabeData instead